# Считывание значения переменной до знака C++

Tags: c++, строки

Есть переменная типа string. К примеру значение этой переменной равно "1,2,аб" нужно чтобы в консоль вывелось
1
2
аб

Comment: Так вам что именно рассказать - как строку поменять или как ее в консоль вывести?...

Comment: Нужно в консоль вывести значение без запятой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию `strtok`. [Пример](https://ideone.com/t0ZATe):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main ()
{
    char str[] = "1,2,аб";
    char delim[] = ",";
    char * pch = strtok (str,delim); 

    while (pch != NULL)                        
    {
        printf("%s ", pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, delim);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А для чего [] и заработает ли если вместо char str будет std::string str?

Comment: @Yarick_Suharik, Конечно, просто этот код и на чистом Си работает (а там объектов string нет).

Comment: Ошибка (активно) E0413 не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "std::string" в "char *"

Comment: Вот [код](https://ideone.com/2X9dlg) со строкой string.

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = "1,2,ab";
replace(s.begin(),s.end(),',',' ');
cout << s << "\n";
```